# Remove extra blank elements in an array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, bounds

I have created an array for a data dump over 35k rows long. I want to only add items in the array that contain 16250 (about 1100 items). So far I've created an array, but it goes all the way to 35k. How do I shorten the limit of the array to stop once the last cell with 16250 is added?

```
Dim A(), i as long, j as integer
nr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))) + 1
nc = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

'CBK Array A()
ReDim A(3 To nr, 1 To nc)

For i = 3 To nr
    For j = 1 To nc
            A(i, j) = Cells(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'create sheet specific array
Dim shArr()
ReDim shArr(3 To nr, 1 To nc)
For i = 3 To nr
    For j = 1 To nc
        If Left(A(i, 4), 5) = "16250" Then
            shArr(i, j) = A(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

So array A goes to 35k, but I want ShArr to only go to around 1100.

I have tried ubound(a), but it included the empty cells even thought I heard from Chat GTP that it shouldn't.

Comment: What are you doing with ShArr ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work (semi-tested).

You can read the range into the array `A` with one line. No need for a loop.

Then get a count of elements starting with "16250" from the 4th column of `A`.

Then `ReDim ShArr` based on that count.

Then load the relevant data into `ShArr`.

```
Dim A() As Variant, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

A = Range("A2", Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value

Dim i As Long, counter As Long

For i = Lbound(A, 1) to Ubound(A, 1)
    If Left(A(i, 4), 5) = "16250" Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next

Dim shArr() As Variant
ReDim shArr(1 to counter, 1 to lastCol)

Dim idx As Long, j As Long
For i = Lbound(A, 1) To Ubound(A, 1)
    If Left(A(i, 4), 5) = "16250" Then
        idx = idx + 1
    
        For j = Lbound(A, 2) To Ubound(A, 2)
            shArr(idx, j) = A(i, j)            
        Next
    End If
Next
```

If the elements beginning with 16250 are alphanumeric, then you can use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` with a wildcard `*` to get the count, and skip the first loop above.

Answer (score 0):

### Match Rows

[image]

```
Sub MatchRows()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_DATA_CELL As String = "A3"
    Const BEGINS_WITH As String = "16250"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 4
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Return the values from the source range in an array.
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_DATA_CELL)
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    
    With sfCell.CurrentRegion
        Set srg = sfCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - sfCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - sfCell.Column)
    End With

    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    If cCount < CRITERIA_COLUMN Then
        MsgBox "There is not enough columns.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value ' assumes 'srCount * cCount > 1'.
    
    ' Return the row numbers of matches in a collection
    
    Dim coll As Collection, sr As Long, sStr As String, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sStr = CStr(sData(sr, CRITERIA_COLUMN))
        If InStr(1, sStr, BEGINS_WITH, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            If Not IsFirstFound Then
                Set coll = New Collection
                IsFirstFound = True
            End If
            coll.Add sr
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If coll Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matches found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Return the matching rows in another array.
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = coll.Count
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim dr As Long, c As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        sr = coll(dr)
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
        Next c
    Next dr
    
    ' Continue using 'dData', e.g. copy next to the source data (see screenshot):
    
'    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = sfCell.Offset(, cCount + 1)
'    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.Resize(drCount, cCount)

'    drg.Value = dData
'    drg.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear

'    MsgBox "Matching rows copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I have taken tidbits from both the answers to help speed up this script.